# ethereum dapple change contact address

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, addresses, dapple

What is the easiest way in dapple to call a contract function from different addresses (set the address which triggers the transaction)?

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear from the question what exactly you are trying to achieve.

However if you want to have to call a contract and later upgrade/change the address of this contract, the usual pattern is

- Describe the contract interface in Solidity (leave function bodies empty)
- Create a [Ethereum name service](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/137) contract. Ropsten testnet comes with [a default ENS contract](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/5ehpr7/ens_has_officially_launched_on_the_ropsten_testnet/).
- For every transaction, look up the latest target contract address from the registry
- Call this contract

Comment: Cool. Feel free to drop in your own answer and mark it correct.